# Test Fail on simulating inserting in database

Tags: c#, .net-core, mocking

Please find link to the project source: https://bitbucket.org/danchi/salescheese/src/master/

There I have problem with testing one domain entity

```
public class RegisterStockUseCaseUnitTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public async void Can_Register_Stock()
        {


            //arrange
            var mockProductRepository = new Mock<IProductRepository>();
            var mockStockRepository = new Mock<IStockRepository>();
            var mockUserRepository = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
            var mockStorageLocationRepository = new Mock<IStorageLocationRepository>();

            mockProductRepository.Setup(repo => repo.FindById(It.IsAny<int>()))
                .Returns(Task.FromResult(true));

            mockUserRepository.Setup(repo => repo.FindById(It.IsAny<string>()))
                .Returns(Task.FromResult(true));

            mockStorageLocationRepository.Setup(repo => repo.FindById(It.IsAny<int>()))
                .Returns(Task.FromResult(true));

            var useCase = new RegisterStockUseCase(mockStockRepository.Object,mockProductRepository.Object,mockUserRepository.Object, mockStorageLocationRepository.Object);

            var mockOutputPort = new Mock<IOutputPort<RegisterStockResponse>>();

            mockOutputPort.Setup(outputPort => outputPort.Handle(It.IsAny<RegisterStockResponse>()));


            //act
            var response =
                await useCase.Handle(new RegisterStockRequest(5, "userId", StockType.Output, UnitOfMeasure.Grams,10,1),
                    mockOutputPort.Object);

            //assert
            Assert.True(response);

        }
    }
```

When I debug I'm getting: **System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'**
I can not figure what, can you please help me ?
P.S. Any idea how to improve tests are welcome. All of them are creating with TDD.
Thanks

**[Update 1]**
[image]

Comment: It seems you didn't set up the Create() method for your stock repository mock.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I had forgot to setup mocking for creating stock, So I had missing next part of the code

```
    mockStockRepository.Setup(repo => repo.Create(It.IsAny<Stock>()))
        .Returns(Task.FromResult(new CreateStockResponse(1, true)));
```